# How to make sure the graph is "on top" of the old ones?

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate

```
Manipulate[
    ListPlot[
        {
            Thread[{Range[1, 10, s], Range[1, 10, s]}],
            Range[1, 10, 1]
        },
        Filling -> Axis,
        GridLines -> Automatic,
        GridLinesStyle -> {{Gray, Dotted}, {Gray, Dotted}},
        Frame -> True,
        PlotRange -> {{0.8, 10}, {0, 10}}
    ],
    {s, {1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.10}}
]
```

Default, the s=1 graph is always there (in orange)
when clicked on s=0.5, I made it look like the new points in blue are added on.

How could I improve the code, so that when I click on s=0.25, only show the "new points" in a different color? and so on.

For example, when click on s=0.25, the lines from s=1 stay in orange, the lines from s=0.5 stay blue, and the new lines from s=0.25 show in red.

Thanks.

Comment: By just removing the `Range[1, 10, 1]` as the second item to be plotted. You plot `Thread[{Range[1, 10, s], Range[1, 10, s]}]` and `Range[1, 10, 1]`, so of course `Range[1, 10, 1]` will always be there. Maybe I didn't quite understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Felix Sorry if it was not clear, by decreasing s, there are more vertical lines. I just want to show the "new" lines in a different color.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be what you are looking for:

```
list = {Thread[{Range[1, 10, 1], Range[1, 10, 1]}]};
snow = 1;
Manipulate[
 If[s != snow, 
  PrependTo[list, Thread[{Range[1, 10, s], Range[1, 10, s]}]]; 
  snow = s];
 ListPlot[list, Filling -> Axis, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> {{Gray, Dotted}, {Gray, Dotted}}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.8, 10}, {0, 10}}], {s, {1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 
   0.10}}]
```

Essentially, list is now storing the history of what you have plotted before and prepends the new data so it's plotted on top.

You may want to use `DeleteDuplicates` after the `PrependTo` command.

Answer (score 1):

```
Manipulate[pos = Position[slist, s, 1, 1][[1, 1]];
 ListPlot[data[[;; pos]], Filling -> Axis, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  Axes -> False, GridLinesStyle -> {{Gray, Dotted}, {Gray, Dotted}}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.8, 10}, {0, 10}}], {{s, First@slist}, slist}, 
 Initialization :> {slist = {1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.10}; 
   d1 = Transpose /@ Transpose[{#, #}] &@Range[1, 10, slist]; 
   data = FoldList[Complement[#2, #] &, d1]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]